# What does CMB polarization has to do with its temperature or temperature anisotropy?

Tags: cosmology, astronomy, cosmic-microwave-background

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_microwave_background#Polarization) says that "*The cosmic microwave background is polarized at the level of a few microkelvin.*". I have no idea what this means. What does temperature anisotropy have to do with polarization? Does it mean that to have polarization there must be temperature anisotropy or deviation from the blackbody spectrum? But why?

Comment: Astronomy SE: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/8317/is-cmb-polarization-simply-the-temperature-gradient-of-the-cmb

Answer (score 1):

To produce polarisation, you need some form of scattering and anisotropic incident light. In a presumed isotropic universe, the anisotropic incident light is created by temperature anisotropies, which are turn is generated by the photon-baryon fluid being not perfectly tightly coupled.

For more info, see Eiichiro Komatsu's notes [here](http://indico.ictp.it/event/8317/session/12/contribution/50/material/slides/) and a video of this lecture [here](http://indico.ictp.it/event/8317/session/12/contribution/50/material/video/).

Comment: I’m a little confused by the remark that the baryon-photon plasma wasn’t tightly coupled. It’s probably more accurate to say the temperature anisotropies arose from primordial density perturbations. Perturbations in the matter can only source perturbations in photon temperature if they are sufficiently tightly coupled.

Comment: @bapowell if the Thomson scattering is efficient (i.e. fluid is tightly coupled) then from the baryons' point of view the photon distribution is isotropic: no polarisation. If the tight coupling relaxes (Thomson scattering no longer efficient) then a temperature anisotropy in the rest frame of the photon-baryon fluid can be created and thus cause polarisation.

Comment: @astronat Could you please also explain what is meant by the statement "_... polarized at the level of a few microkelvin._" that I quoted in the question from Wikipedia? Does it mean that the CMB polarization is caused by a temperature anisotropy of the order of few microkelvin?